# How do I find out what serif font is being used in the Day One mac app?

Tags: applications, font

I use the [Day One](http://dayoneapp.com/) regularly and love it. I also write a lot (for work) and have found that Day One serif font and style making writing such a pleasure. I'd like to use the font in my other word processors (particularly Scrivener) and am willing to purchase it but can't figure out what it is. How would I go about finding out what it is?

- I've emailed the app author but got no response from him.
- I've poked around the `Contents/Resources` folder in the application but only found a fixed-with font.
- Here is a screenshot (but I can't imagine that's very helpful).
  [image]
  I appreciate any leads.

Comment: I don't have a technical technique you can use to determine which font is used in the app, but it looks to me like it's Baskerville, which is included with OS X.

Answer (score 2):

This application on the web helped me out a couple of times:

http://www.whatfontis.com/

Just take a screenshot of some words which are typed with a particular font (preferably with a big size) and upload the screenshot.

I am not affiliated with the site in any way, I'm just a satisfied user. Give it a try. Otherwise you could try to mail the developers of Day One.

Answer (score 2):

It's either Hoefler Text or Baskerville. Check Preferences > Appearance to see which one is selected. I think both of them come with OS X, so you shouldn't have to buy anything.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the main Sans font. which is probably Avenir

http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/avenir/

https://dayone.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200145945-The-Day-One-main-window-goes-blank

Answer (score -1):

It's called "Anonymous Pro" on the iPhone app